# Is there a way to redirect 404s from a nested [slug] path to use the parent file in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If i have a file structure in this fashion:
`/shop/index.ts`
`/shop/pants/[slug].ts`
is there a way to redirect 404s to `/shop/` that way the user just sees the parent directory instead of a 404 page?

Comment: Are your pages server-side rendered (`getServerSideProps`) or statically generated (`getStaticProps`)?

Comment: statically generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what data fetching methods you are using (or not using), for example with `getServerSideProps` it can be something like that:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // You are probably fetching data somehow from api?
  const res = await getData(context.params.slug)

  if (res.status === 404) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/shop',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      // Your default case with data
    }
  }
}
```

Same works for [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) too